# Resizing uploaded image in Drupal using imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, image, drupal, resize

I'm trying to resize an image that is uploaded to Drupal via a form. The code I have for it is:

```
//Image resizing
//Get file and if it's not the default one - resize it.
$img = file_load($form_state['values']['event_image']);
if($img->fid != 1) {
  //Get the image size and calculate ratio
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img->uri);
  if($width/$height > 1) {
    $new_width = 60;
    $new_height = $height/($width/60);
  } else if($width/$height < 1) {
    $new_height = 60;
    $new_width = $width/($height/60);
  } else {
    $new_width = 60;
    $new_height = 60;
  }
  //Create image
  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img->uri, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img->uri);
  } else {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($img->uri);
  }
  //Resize image
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
  //Save image as jpeg
  imagejpeg($image_p, file_create_url($img->uri), 80);
  //Clean up
  imagedestroy($image_p);
  //Store the image permanently.
  $img->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
}
file_save($img);
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is to save the new file (with the smaller size) over the old one that got uploaded.

The problem I'm getting is PHP throws a warning on `imagejpeg($image_p, file_create_url($img->uri), 80);` saying:

`Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'http://localhost:8888/drupal/sites/default/files/pictures/myimage.png' for writing: No such file or directory in event_creation_form_submit()`

Because of this, the image isn't resizing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Drupal has image resizing functions built right in is there any reason you can't use those?

Comment: Hi Clive, I had no idea Drupal had those - is it just http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_resize/7 that you're talking about?

Comment: There are quite a few, [`image_scale`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_scale/7), [`image_crop`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_crop/7), [`image_scale_and_crop`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_scale_and_crop/7), [`image_rotate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_rotate/7) and I think a few others

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use the core image cache module? It can resize your graphics in any way. You can even have different sizes for different needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clive pointed out - the fix was to use image_scale. Here is an extract of working code:

```
//Image resizing
//Get file and if it's not the default one - resize it.
$img = file_load($form_state['values']['event_image']);
if($img->fid != 1) {
  //Get the image size and calculate ratio
  $newImage = image_load($img->uri);
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img->uri);
  if($width/$height >= 1) {
    image_scale($newImage, 60);
  } else {
    image_scale($newImage, null, 60);
  }
  //Save image
  image_save($newImage);
  $img->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  }
```